# Debugging: "Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:"

Tags: selenium

I am learning Pythons so please bear with me.

I adopted LinkedIn-Easy-Apply-Bot from: https://github.com/voidbydefault/LinkedIn-Easy-Apply-Bot

While the bot is working perfectly fine on my test account but when I change the email ID/password to real account (with everything being the same), I start getting these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/Documents/LinkedIn-Easy-Apply-Bot/linkedineasyapply.py", line 124, in apply_jobs
    job_results = self.browser.find_element_by_class_name("jobs-search-results")
  File "/home/me/PycharmProjects/Better-LinkedIn-EasyApply-Bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 766, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "/home/me/PycharmProjects/Better-LinkedIn-EasyApply-Bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1251, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/home/me/PycharmProjects/Better-LinkedIn-EasyApply-Bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 430, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/me/PycharmProjects/Better-LinkedIn-EasyApply-Bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".jobs-search-results"}
  (Session info: chrome=102.0.5005.61)
```

I have tried deleting chromedriver to ensure version conflicts do not exit, I have tried adding time.sleep(5) in line 124 (above) and also tried driver.implicitly_wait(10). Unfortunately, the error persists with my real account.

Note that there are no issues with my real account if used manually. I am able to apply all sorts of jobs whether EasyApply or otherwise and the bot is working 100% fine on my test account hence the elements the code is looking for exist.

Please help in fixing the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: linkedin doesn't like automation. They make money selling access to their APIs for direct data access. Have you debugged your script? - When you try it with your real account, are you watching it? are you able to see the job results on screen when your script runs?  - And if so, have you paused the script to verify the DOM element with devtools?

Comment: I am able to see job results, it's just the bot fails to apply. I am trying to debug but not getting anywhere (due to lack of experience). I think I'll get there. Thanks for your comment.